# Creating swap files faster

Tags: linux, filesystems, amazon-ec2, swap

I'm using Amazon EC2 and wish to be able to quickly generate large swapfiles (~10+GB) on instance startup.  Unfortunately, I/O speed on my instances (c1.xlarge) is slow enough (20 MB/s) that this operation takes 10+ minutes, which is unacceptable for my usage.

I am aware that the swapfiles must be pre-alocated to use, so that I can't use sparse files.

However, is there some command to allocate blocks w/out spending the large amount of time zero-ing out the blocks?  Also, if this command exists, am I correct in assuming that a page in the swapfile is zero'd out before a user process has access to it (mitigating security concerns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't indicate what method you were trying to avoid.

Traditionally, you would issue a `dd` command that would in turn pump out a zero'd file of the appropriate size, then run `mkswap`, add the entry to `/etc/fstab`, and then `swapon` to activate it.  I've attached a rather hastily-written example shell script that I'm sure has errors (it's late where I'm at and the `fstab` entry is far from perfect)

```
#!/bin/bash
# --- allocate 10Gbyte of swap space as 10 separate 1Gbyte files
# --- that are brought online sequentially during processing
for swpidx in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
do
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile.$swpidx bs=16738 count=65536
  mkswap /swapfile.$swpidx
  echo "/swapfile.$swpidx    swap    swap    default    0 0" >> /etc/fstab
  swapon -a
done
swapon -s
```

However, it sounds like you are trying to avoid this method.  **The fastest solution that I could provide would be to use a swap partition, which does not require the zero-out process, and can be brought online in minutes.**  If your instance is running LVM and you have an existing volume group that you could carve a partition out of, that would work just as well, and the allocation could be completed in just a few minutes.

I think I should mention that carving out a swap space of this size is a bit unusual, even for a server; and I only say that because most servers have several gigs of RAM attached when dealing with programs/data of that size.  Not to pry or anything, but are you really needing that much swap space?

Another thing you may wish to consider is re-tuning your workload, rather than trying to dynamically allocate swap space.  While it's great to have that much "on-demand", as you yourself pointed out, it will quickly become a bottleneck due to the slow I/O throughput on your server instance.  By the time you exhaust your memory and you're essentially "living in swap", you'll find that the 20Mbyte/sec transfer rate turns your instance into a 386SX.

Answer (score 5):

I have success using 'fallocate' command. It takes less than 1 second.

```
sudo fallocate -l 10G /swapfile
```

Afterwards, you can run mkswap. For more info, you can use the great Digital Ocean tutorial for ubuntu here, that may work without modification for other linux flavors, at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use a loopback device to put swap on sparse file:
http://www.option-c.com/xwiki/Loop_Mounting_Swap_Partition

Answer (score 0):

Your c1.xlarge instance should have, or be able to have, some substantial **local instance store** (ephemeral, won't persist across launch).  You may have to be sure the space is allocated when launching.  I've not done this so I can't give you details.  I would definitely not use a swap file.